# Как сменить shell на bash в UNIX

Tags: unix

Всем привет,помогите с вопросом

Comment: просто запустите программу *bash*

Comment: Вот здесь все написано https://pingvinus.ru/note/change-shell

Comment: где вы берете unix в 2020 году...